# Azure Function Application Works In Debug, Timeouts Intermittently on Azure

Tags: azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

[I am using this example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-postgresql/tree/master/samples/IoT%20Demo) to attempt to replicate capturing data from an ESP32S3 controller through AzureIoTHub, Azure Function Application, and output to a PostgreSQL on Azure. Here is the function:

```
    module.exports = function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    var pg = require('pg');
    //const config = "postgres://<username>:<password>@<postgres servername>:5432/<database>";
    
    const config = {
                        host: 'myserver.postgres.database.azure.com',
                        user: 'granted', 
                        password: 'mypassword',
                        database: 'telemetry',
                        port: 5432,
                        ssl: true
    };
    
    var client = new pg.Client(config);
    const query = 'insert into tempdata(deviceid, data) values(1,\'' + JSON.stringify(IoTHubMessages) + '\');';
    context.log(query);
    //client.connect();
    //client.query(query);
    

    //client.end();
    //await client.end();
    //context.log('insert completed successfully!');    


    client.connect(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            client
                .query(query)
                .then(() => {
                context.log('insert completed successfully!');
                client.end(console.log('Closed client connection'));
                 })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .then(() => {
                context.log('Finished execution, exiting now');
                        });
            }
        });
        
};
```

When run through the debugger in VSCode, this works. Flawlessly. Every time. When I install the function code to Azure, it will work once, then, go into a five minute timeout, for no reason I can discern, then it will work again, once, then a five minute timeout. Here are the logs from Azure:

> 2023-08-08T21:25:06Z   [Information]   insert into tempdata(deviceid,
> data) values(1,'["{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature":
> 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}"]');
> 2023-08-08T21:25:06Z   [Information]   insert completed successfully!
> 2023-08-08T21:25:06Z   [Information]   Finished execution, exiting now
> 2023-08-08T21:30:06Z   [Error]   Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by
> function 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub3' (Id:
> 'c7fddcd1-3953-4562-be81-0f04a8f29b48'). Initiating cancellation.
> 2023-08-08T21:30:06Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub3'
> (Failed, Id=c7fddcd1-3953-4562-be81-0f04a8f29b48, Duration=300017ms)
> 2023-08-08T21:30:18Z   [Information]   Executing
> 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub3' (Reason='(null)',
> Id=70402ee6-e981-44ef-950c-2c7ced54156b) 2023-08-08T21:30:18Z
> [Information]   Trigger Details: PartionId: 0, Offset:
> 4295065936-4295069176, EnqueueTimeUtc:
> 2023-08-08T20:32:44.3110000+00:00-2023-08-08T20:34:14.7240000+00:00,
> SequenceNumber: 1831-1840, Count: 10 2023-08-08T21:30:18Z   [Verbose]
> Sending invocation id: '70402ee6-e981-44ef-950c-2c7ced54156b
> 2023-08-08T21:30:18Z   [Verbose]   Posting invocation
> id:70402ee6-e981-44ef-950c-2c7ced54156b on
> workerId:8ea99dea-4f2a-4325-854e-eb18ae1d2ab7 2023-08-08T21:30:18Z
> [Information]   insert into tempdata(deviceid, data) values(1,'["{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}","{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.40}","{
> "Temperature": 82.22}","{ "Temperature": 82.22}"]');
> 2023-08-08T21:30:19Z   [Information]   insert completed successfully!
> 2023-08-08T21:30:19Z   [Information]   Finished execution, exiting now
> 2023-08-08T21:35:18Z   [Error]   Timeout value of 00:05:00 exceeded by
> function 'Functions.IoTHub_EventHub3' (Id:
> '70402ee6-e981-44ef-950c-2c7ced54156b'). Initiating cancellation.

Run from debug, this takes only a few milliseconds. It's not a five minute process. It's one single execution of the query and it's done. I know I can set the timeout to 10 minutes, but since this query is completing in far less than the timeout, I'm assuming I've done something foolish inside the function that's keeping it from completing.

UPDATE 8/9/2023:
Based on the comments, I changed the code to this:

```
module.exports = async function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    var pg = require('pg');
    //const config = "postgres://<username>:<password>@<postgres servername>:5432/<database>";
    
    const config = {
                        host: 'arduinodata.postgres.database.azure.com',
                        user: 'granted', 
                        password: 'mypassword',
                        database: 'mydatabase',
                        port: 5432,
                        ssl: true
    };
    
    var client = new pg.Client(config);
    const query = 'insert into tempdata(deviceid, data) values(1,\'' + JSON.stringify(IoTHubMessages) + '\');';
    context.log(query);
    client.connect();
    client.query(query);
    

    client.end();
    await client.end();
    context.log('insert completed successfully!');  

/*
    client.connect(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            client
                .query(query)
                .then(() => {
                context.log('insert completed successfully!');
                client.end(console.log('Closed client connection'));
                 })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            .then(() => {
                context.log('Finished execution, exiting now');
                        });
            }
        });*/
        
};
```

Running from the debugger results in this error:

> [error] Worker uncaught exception (learn more:
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097909 ): Error: Connection
> terminated     at
> C:\Users\grant\Documents\GitHub\Arduino\AppFunc\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:526:17
> at process.processTicksAndRejections
> (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

In short, feels like I'm going backwards. I was at least writing to the database before.

Comment: could tell the details like tested locally and then deployed to Azure. Is it also timeout locally also?

Comment: use   `await client.end();` Make sure your PostgreSQL client connection is closed after every query execution. In your code, you have commented out the client.end() calls. Uncomment them so that the client connection is closed after each query execution. Not closing connections properly can lead to resource exhaustion and could potentially cause timeouts.

Comment: good to use `await client.end();` in final block

Comment: But there is a second client.end in there a bit further down. I'll retest using 'await' but that was generating errors.

Comment: Switching the commented code out and using 'await client.end()' results in an error in the debugger: [error] Worker uncaught exception (learn more: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097909 ): Error: Connection terminated     at C:\Users\grant\Documents\GitHub\Arduino\AppFunc\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:526:17     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Comment: And, in order to use 'await', I had to add ASYNC to the function definition. Not sure if that's causing this error or not.

Comment: Hi @GrantFritchey can you share more details on your solution architecture and data flow. More specifically how is the Azure function linked with the IoT Hub data? Is it through Event Hub triggering? If so, can you share the method signature of the Azure function. Please refer this sample Python Implementation of [Event Hub Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#example)

Comment: ```module.exports = async function (context, IoTHubMessages) {
    var pg = require('pg');
    //const config = "postgres://<username>:<password>@<postgres servername>:5432/<database>";
    const config = {
                        host: 'iotpgserver.postgres.database.azure.com',
                        user: 'iotadmin@iotpgserver',     
                        password: <password>,
                        database: 'iotdemo',
                        port: 5432,
                        ssl: true
    };
 ```

Comment: ```var client = new pg.Client(config);
    const query = 'insert into iotdata(deviceid, data) values(' + eventHubMessages.deviceId + ',\'' + JSON.stringify(IoTHubMessages) + '\');';
    context.log(query);
    client.connect();
    client.query(query);
    await client.end();
    context.log('insert completed successfully!'); 
};```